# Too cold water from shower

Tags: plumbing, shower

The water in my shower is too cold no matter what I do. Hot water from the sink in the same bathroom is 110 degrees F, but the water from the show/tub maxes out at around 85F.

This is a new development, and I do not know what caused it. The shower previously provided sufficiently hot water.

I suspect the cartridge is either bad, needs cleaned, or adjusted. I cannot figure out how to get at it, though.

See the photos below, particularly the last one. I cannot physically access the cartridge, because of that silver cover thing on top. I cannot see any way to remove the silver thing either - so far it's resisted my every attempt (tried prying off with a screwdriver, and tried unscrewing with a large wrench).

Can you suggest how I might get at the cartridge, or what other course of action I should take?

[image: Full view of weird shower thing with no labels or identifying information anywhere]

[image: View of area with the valves]

[image: the valve/cartridge in question]

Comment: Supplying brand/model of the faucet system is bound to help. That way, someone can look up the instructions for you. Barring that, the top hole (about 10 o'clock) seems to have a slotted screw head visible. Have you tried unscrewing that? Is that escutcheon ring almost looks like it's attached to the larger panel behind it, though, at least from the last image. At this point, as much as you've damaged it, you may consider just cutting it off and taking a look at how it was held on there. I can't image those bends and marks from the pipe wrench will be satisfactory long term.

Comment: First of all, put away the large wrench! Brawn isn't going to be the answer here. The problem is almost certainly in the thermostatic cartridge. Gaining access requires either specific knowledge of how to do it or great patience. It appears from the pic that you have the correct valve. I assume the one above it controls water flow. The two holes in the chrome ring may provide access to a couple of retaining screws or they may be there to enable the ring to be unscrewed. Do you know the manufacturer?

Comment: @Freeman, I would love to figure out the brand and model numbers, but I cannot find any kind of label or anything like that.

Comment: @HoneyDo that's right, the one immediately above controls flow. I know the last picture makes it look like there are screws, but that's actually a continuation of the valve/cartridge itself - it looks like there is a T blocking it in behind the silver bit (you can see the edge of the T at the top there, under the black/open space - that extends to the sides).

Comment: (FWIW I'm not worried about the appearance of this thing - I can't stand it and will replace the thing wholesale in the future. Just want a hot bath for now. Sadly, it doesn't seem like a simple matter of ripping the thing off the wall and putting a regular faucet in - the pipes only exit the wall near the top of the fixture - so it'll be a matter of cutting the tile and running new / extra pipes to the bath faucet area.)

Comment: Okay, this is just a guess. You may have to remove the entire panel behind all three of the control knobs. Try removing the other two knobs and using a putty knife try to gently pry off the long plate. It may pop off.

Comment: the whole aluminium thing looks like a prefabricated module that connects to pre-existing bath valves, start removing fittings until a way to open it is revealed.

Comment: @HoneyDo I've been working on prying that off - and it looks like it's just a sticker one top of the aluminum. But, it's removal is blocked by the silver thing in question - making me think the silver thing is meant to pop off, somehow. I might just need a bigger hammer. :)

Comment: @Jasen It's actually distinct from the wall - like, I can pull the aluminum block away from the wall at the bottom (2-3 inches) - it seems like it's only connected at the top. However it is connected, it is not connected very well - my pushing and pulling shifted the whole thing to the side a few inches. I went into the smaller bathroom behind this one, which has a sink directly behind this shower - and the sink had been moved by my efforts as well. Is this whole silly thing really just held on by the pipes?!

Comment: @Jasen There is however one screw on each side (barely visible in the first photo - see the little notch on the side of the block, near the bottom of the mirror). So far I have not been able to budge either screw even a little.

Comment: typically yes, these retrofit shower modules attach to pipe nipples and/or valve sockets.

Comment: Um is that an LCD temp display? I have installed bath fixtures that had presets and you could not go above them.

Comment: @EdBeal, it appears to be an LCD display. It has not functioned since I purchased the house. The water temperature is not matching the presets (which are in celsius, going up to 48C, e.g. 118F) - instead topping out at about 85F. This did not use to be case - you could get painfully hot bathwater previously.